# Изменение регистра букв

Tags: java

Не могу разобраться с return-ом:( Ретурн нужен для ЮнитТеста... через сисаут всё работает отлично.

```
private transfer str;
{
    String str = "Hello World";
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    str = "";
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
            c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        else
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        str += c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить тип возвращаемого результата, то есть `public string transfer_str()`

Comment: наверно, код неполный

Answer (score 0):

String не изменяемый, потому надо создать или новую строку, или пользоваться StringBuilder().

Comment: Безусловно, в подобной задаче (наращивание строки **в цикле**) надо использовать StringBuilder().